# Backsolving Counting Problem

Tags: combinatorics

Lauren mixes and matches all of her jeans, skirts, and vests to make different outfits. If she can make a total of 24 different outfits, each consisting of one pair of jeans, one shirt, and one vest, which of the following could NOT be the number of shirts that lauren Has?

A.2

B.3

C.4

D.5

E.6

Comment: Which answer is not a divisor of $24$?

Comment: @amWhy  5 is not a divisor of 24.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

suppose there are $j$ jeans, $s$ skirts and $v$ vests, then :

number of different outfits  =  $j\times s\times v = 24$